# scope of array (array refreshes with page refresh)

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, scope, submit

I have this code:

application.js

```
var userArray = []; 

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#signupform").submit(function(e) {
        var user = {
            name: $('#pname').val(),
            email: $('#email').val()
        };
        userArray.push(user);
        var html = new EJS({url: 'templates/usershow.ejs'}).render(user);
        var content = document.getElementById('content');
        content.innerHTML = content.innerHTML + html;
        $("#signupform").remove();   
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>it IT</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="application.css" />
  <script src="jquery.js"></script> 
  <script src="application.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="ejs_production.js"></script>
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    <h1>it IT</h1>
    <div id="signup">
        <form id="signupform">
            Name: <input type="text" name="pname" id="pname"><br>
            Email: <input type="text" name="email" id="email"><br>
            <input type="submit" value="sign up">
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="signin"></div>
    <div id="content"><h2>Name : Email</h2></div>
</body>
</html>
```

templates/usershow.ejs

```
<ul>
   <li><%= userArray[userArray.length - 1].name %> - <%= userArray[userArray.length - 1].email %></li>
</ul>
```

In the js file, I have declared an array outside of the function. I am trying to push the user to the array from within the function. All goes well until I refresh the page...the array gets refreshed too - I'm a newb, but it seems like a scope problem. I'm trying to keep the array intact, even after a page refresh - so I can refer to it at other points in the file. Any help would be appreciated. Also, does anyone have a good link to where I could read about creating sessions (for sign in/sign out) in javascript?

Comment: HTML, javascript etc. is stateless, once a page is reloaded or navigated away from, all variable values are lost, that's the nature of javascript. To have persistent storage you'll have to use localStorage, cookies or the server to store the values.

Comment: thanks...which would you recommend?

Comment: @ewizard that depends entirely on what you have available and your target audience. If they are predominantly IE 9 < users then localstorage is probably out of the window. Your safest bet is to use server side sessions or cookies.